# How to clear the list of "Notification Area Icons" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, notifications, notification-area

I can't seem to find a way to clear the list of "Notification Area Icons" in Windows 7. Unfortunately I had installed a download manager (GetRight) which by default creates a tray icon for each download. I quickly disabled this but still have a ton of entries in that menu and it's annoying.

I found an article that had me navigate to this key in the registry...

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify
```

delete IconStreams and PastIconStreams, then restart, but it did not clear the list.

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to hear you solved your problem. If, in the future, you'd like a less cumbersome method of doing that, you could grab [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner).

Aside from being an extremely handy Disk-Cleanup-on-steroids application, it has the option to easily wipe those out too -- under the Advanced group, tick "Tray Notifications Cache" and then hit "Run Cleaner". You'll still have to restart explorer.exe, but it is a bit quicker than circumnavigating the Registry. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need to delete these entries, then open the Task Manager to force-quit explorer.exe and then run explorer.exe again. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Freeware tool [Notification Area Cleaner for Windows 7](http://www.itsamples.com/notification-area-cleaner.html) deletes the registry entries and restarts `explorer.exe`.

It comes as a standalone `.exe`cutable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Freeware tool [Notification Area Cleaner](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-clean-notification-area-icon-cache) deletes the registry entries and restarts `explorer.exe`.

It comes as a standalone `.bat`ch file: [image]

[image]

Full source code:

```
@echo off

:: Notification Area Cleaner
:: Created by Hally Master hally_master (at) yahoo (dot) com
:: Distributed by www.7tutorials.com
:: WARNING! This utility restarts your shell (Explorer.exe) and clears your notification area icon cache

taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify" /v IconStreams /f
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify" /v PastIconsStream /f
start "Shell Restarter" /d "%systemroot%" /i /normal explorer.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

```
taskkill / im explorer.exe /f
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify"/v IconStreams/f
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify"/v PastIconsStreams/f
start "ShellRestarter"/d "%systemroot%"/i/normal explorer.exe
```