# Removing entries from notification area settings

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear the list of “Notification Area Icons” in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/122774/how-to-clear-the-list-of-notification-area-icons-in-windows-7)

I want to customize notification area icon settings. Settings should have entries of currently installed applications. But it's showing all the applications I have ever installed. Finding the entry to customize the notification settings is tiresome!

Even one application have two entries of two different version including previous version. **How can i remove entries of uninstalled applications?**

[image: Uninstalled application still have entries in notification area icon settings]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to do this is [through the registry](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/clean-up-past-notification-icons-in-windows-vista/) from what I've found, but it isn't too hard!

You'll need to open `regedit` to start - but don't worry, you aren't modifying anything major.

In your Registry Editor, search for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify`

You will see three things. Select `IconStreams` and `PastIconsStream`, and delete them.

From here, you need to restart `explorer.exe` - you can either kill it in the task manager and restart it, or simply log on and off. You're notification area list is now cleaned up!